# How to discover all devices in MQTT-enabled LAN?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, paho

In my LAN there are several MQTT-enabled devices (Tasmota) and I am writing an MQTT client (Javascript, through mosquitto websocket and PAHO client library).

Which is the best way to discover all online devices in the LAN and their corresponding device name? I thought using the LWT message that every device sends, but I don't know how to subscribe to all LWT message from unknown devices.

The LWT "Online" messages are coming through with this path: `tele/<device_name>/LWT`, but I don't want to subscribe to ALL "tele" messages, as they are too many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use single level wildcard topics.

e.g.

```
tele/+/LWT
```

This will get you all the topics that start with `tele` and end with `LWT` with only on element in the middle.